# How to get RDP Disconnected sessions using quser command

Tags: powershell

I found the following code by Theo in a reply to a previous post a few years back, I have modified it to suit my needs but there is one issue I cannot seem to overcome.

If a machine has mulitple people (lets say 17) logged into the machine and disconnected, the results show the machine name 17 times but the same username, idletime and logontime. So it's not actually returning each user that is logged in.

I cannot user qwinsta because I want to see the idletime and logontime which quser is able to provide. I attempted to reply to the original post but because I was not answering the question my post was deleted, so I am starting a new one.

Does anyone have any idea what I am misssing?

This is the original code.

```
function Get-RemoteSessions {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string[]]$ComputerName = 'localhost'
    )
    foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        Write-Verbose "Getting session information for $Computer"
        # create an object to fill in later
        $obj = "" | Select-Object UserName, @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$Computer}}, 
                                  SessionName, ID, State, IdleTime, LogonTime, Error
        try {
            quser /server:$Computer 2>&1 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {
                $items = $_.Trim() -split '\s{2,}'
                $obj.UserName = $items[0].TrimStart(">")
                # If session is disconnected different fields will be selected
                if ($items[2] -like 'Disc*') {
                    $obj.SessionName = $null
                    $obj.Id          = $items[1]
                    $obj.State       = $items[2]
                    # IdleTime displays the number of minutes that have elapsed since the last keyboard or 
                    # mouse input from a session. Its format is number-of-days + hours:minutes
                    $obj.IdleTime    = $items[3]
                    $obj.LogonTime   = $items[4..($items.GetUpperBound(0))] -join ' '
                }
                else {
                    $obj.SessionName = $items[1]
                    $obj.Id          = $items[2]
                    $obj.State       = $items[3]
                    $obj.IdleTime    = $items[4]
                    $obj.LogonTime   = $items[5]
                }
                # reformat the IdleTime property
                $obj.IdleTime = '{0} days, {1} hours, {2} minutes' -f ([int[]]([regex]'^(?:(\d+)\+)?(\d+):(\d+)').Match($obj.IdleTime).Groups[1..3].Value | ForEach-Object { $_ })
                # output the object
                $obj
            }
        } 
        catch {
            $obj.Error = $_.Exception.Message
            $obj
        }
    }
}

## Clear Host Console
Clear-Host

$ExcludedServers = 'EXCLUDESRV01', 'EXCLUDESRV02', 'EXCLUDESRV03'
## Read the list of Servers excluding the ones in $ExcludedServers
$Servers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\Desktop\Active or Disc users\Servers\Servers.txt' | 
           Where-Object { $ExcludedServers -notcontains $_ }

# get all remote sessions on all servers
$allSessions = Get-RemoteSessions -ComputerName $Servers -Verbose

# filter the open sessions from the $allRemoteUsers
$openSessions = $allSessions| Where-Object {$_.Username -ne 'Administrator' -and $_.State -notlike 'Disc*'}
# and do the same for the disconnected sessions
$disconnected = $allSessions | Where-Object {$_.Username -ne 'Administrator' -and $_.State -like 'Disc*' }

## Define Path for the Out File and make sure the path for the output file exists
$reportPath = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Active or Disc users\Out'
$null = New-Item -Path $reportPath -ItemType Directory -Force

if (@($openSessions).Count) {
    # write a file for the open sessions
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $reportPath -ChildPath ('RDP_Connected_Users_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv' -f (Get-Date))
    $openSessions | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Host "No open user sessions found"
}

if (@($disconnected).Count) {
    # and another for the disconnected sessions
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $reportPath -ChildPath ('RDP_DisConnected_Users_{0:yyyyMMdd}.csv' -f (Get-Date))
    $disconnected | Export-Csv -Path $outFile -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Host "No disconnected sessions found"
}
```